# Frame centric (tmux like) emacs workflow

Tags: buffers, frames

I really like the tmux workflow where one could split a window into multiple planes and then create a second window which could be also split multiple times, so one could have a window where some monitoring services are running and another where he edits configuration files. In tmux parlance windows are in a way workspaces between which you could navigate and planes are arbitrary splits of these workspaces.

I would like to be able to imitate the tmux way in emacs i.e. make windows local to a certain entity (let's call it a workspace) and be able to  split an emacs frame into multiple windows in one workspace then open the second workspace and be able to split it arbitrarily again, so if I am editing a very big file and a smaller one I could occupy a workspace with windows containing relevant code of the big file  and then without destroying all the windows jump to edit the smaller one, and then back again, is this possible ?

Comment: Please describe "the tmux workflow" which you would like to imitate. And please check the Emacs manual for what an Emacs window is and what an Emacs frame is, as your question currently is unclear.

Comment: This is not an answer because I'm not sure how to use-it, but I read that eyebrowse-mode (https://github.com/wasamasa/eyebrowse) could be used to replicate the behavior you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the impression that what you call "workspace" correspond to something like "frames" or "window-configuration"s.  whereas your "planes" are more like Emacs's "windows".

So you can use `C-x 5 2` to create new frames in which you can create subwindows with `C-x 2` and `C-x 3`.

If you don't want to use frames but would rather do all that within a single frame, you can use window-configurations instead.  E.g. `C-x r w a` will store the current window-configuration in register "a", so you can return to it with `C-x r j a`.

Comment: the window-configuration thing was really what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

You should use the excellent `perspective` package. You can download it from emacs package management tool. `perspective` will allow you to create, maintain and switch between *workspaces* as you have defined them. The tmux-like window configuration is not lost when you are switching between `perspectives`.